# Microphone sound auto adjusting with pulseaudio-echo-cancellation on

Tags: 16.04, pulseaudio

So, whenever I activate my pulseaudio-echo-cancellation module, my mic starts auto-adjusting its volume. No applications are open.

I am using a USB Headset with a microhpone.

The auto-adjusting only appears with the module on.